# how to increment variable name by 1 in php

Tags: php, arrays, increment

I have an associative array in which i bind a string to a variable.
Is there an easy way to increment the variable by 1?

```
$lang = array(  
    'All Articles' => $t0,
    'Main Articles' => $t1,
    'Archived Articles' => $t2,
    'Search Articles' => $t3,
    'Search for' => $t4,
    'Page' => $t5,
    'from' => $t6,
    // and so on...
);
```

So i am looking for something like that creates the vars `$t0` till `$t160` per example.

I tried this but does not work:

```
$i = 0;
$lang = array(  
    'All Articles' => $t.$i++,
    'Main Articles' => $t.$i++,
    'Archived Articles' => $t.$i++,
    'Search Articles' => $t.$i++,
    'Search for' => $t.$i++,
    'Page' => $t.$i++,
    'from' => $t.$i++,
```

**Where it is used for:**

Administrator stores the translated string into a `.txt` file by filling in a form.
A txt file looks like this:

```
Alle Produkte
Hauptartikel
Archivierte Artikel
// and so on
```

Then read the content of the text file:

```
$translationfile = 'data/translations.txt'; 
$lines_translationfile = file($translationfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of the translations.txt file into an array
for ($x = 0; $x <= 160; $x++) {
    ${"t".$x} = $lines_translationfile[$x];
}
include 'includes/lang.php'; // the associative array
```

Now in the page i can easily translate a string with `$lang['All Articles']`

Comment: You could dynamically build this array with incrementing variable names, but honestly, you should rethink your design. Having a large number of numerically designated variables can be a nightmare to work with. Any reason why these 160 variables aren't created as an array or object immediately?

Comment: Explanation added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array of your keys, then you can use [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine them directly with the lines from the file:

```
$translationfile = 'data/translations.txt'; 
$lines_translationfile = file($translationfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // all lines of the translations.txt file into an array
$keys = array('All Articles','Main Articles','Archived Articles','Search Articles','Search for','Page','from', ...);
$lang = array_combine($keys, $lines_translationfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
$lang = array(  
    'All Articles' => ${"t".$i++},
    'Main Articles' => ${"t".$i++},
    'Archived Articles' => ${"t".$i++},
    'Search Articles' => ${"t".$i++},
    'Search for' => ${"t".$i++},
    'Page' => ${"t".$i++},
    'from' => ${"t".$i++});
```

Comment: @john It works, but consider Nick's answer. It's shorter, cleaner and more efficient.